# Twitter error of 'Missing or invalid url parameter'

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I have used the following Plugin [voycey/CakePHP-Twitter-API-v1.1-Full](https://github.com/voycey/CakePHP-Twitter-API-v1.1-Full) to send text tweets to my account from a CakePHP based application.

The author provides a forked version of [abraham/twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) which should be used with the plugin.

I have got it working and can send a simple tweet as follows

```
$result = $this->Twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status'=>'This is a test message'));
```

I then tried to send an image, but after some research found that abraham's version (and therefore voycey's) did not support the use of 'update_with_media'. Several people suggested that a newer forked version did support this protocol, this being [tomi-heiskanen/twitteroauth](https://github.com/tomi-heiskanen/twitteroauth)

Sending standard text tweets still work with this new version, but when I try to send an image using the following

```
$file = "img/facebook.jpg";
$filename = "facebook.jpg";
$binary = fopen($file, "rb");
$image = fread($binary, filesize($file));
fclose($binary);

$result = $this->Twitter->post('statuses/update_with_media', array('media[]' => "{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$filename}"));
```

I get the following error returned

> [code] => 195 [message] => Missing or invalid url parameter.

Despite researching this and other sites, I cannot find a solution that works.

Comment: I would suggest googling "Twitter API 'Missing or invalid url parameter'".  There are *many* similar issues & resolutions... like [this](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/pull/232) and perhaps of interest, the Twitter API documentation which says media is a multi-part request: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: I've spent ALL day googling it, including the article you refer to which does not provide a solution, but just states the spec. If I knew which part of my solution is broken I could fix it.

Comment: I googled it and this question was the top result :/

Comment: I got this same error. This could be the case of twitter's shadow banning. I regenerated the tokens and it works again, not sure when they will disable it again.